# Has_many + has_many through parent of same class until root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

We've got a class called `Taxon`, a `taxon` will have a parent, which might have a parent, etc ... which eventually leads to a root taxon.

I'm adding a relationship to `Taxon`: `OnboardingRequirement`, so that `Taxon` will `have_many :onboarding_requirements`.

I want the relationship to also encompass its parent relationships and grandparents and great(^n)grandparents.

Is it possible to compound a relationship? Is it possible to set taxon to `has_many :onboarding_requirements, through: :parent` *and* without the `through`?

I know it would be possible to just loop through the parents and concat all `:onboarding_requirements` -- and the tree isn't terribly tall (4 or 5 at the deepest), but this seems like something that I should solve in the relationship, and not compute it at calltime.

Using Rails 3.2.x, Ruby 2.1.x

Comment: I set it up like you described, but the `has_many, through` standard approach results in: `SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from /Users/Joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
`.  You will have to get rid of `have_many, through` and write a custom method to build the query as you wish, but your way of looping up the tree is probably fine, and easier.